# Acer laptop Win 10 Won't Turn On Wifi (used to work)

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1703

I'm working on a laptop for a client. It's an old Acer 5253-bz692. WiFi was working until the client came to pick it up (of course). I updated to WIn 10 1703 and WiFi continued to work. The only thing I did that could be related is I upgraded the RAM, which is nearby the WiFi card.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Settings > WiFi Settings > Turn On WiFi (it shows as off). That
   switches the toggle, but never turns on. If I reload the WiFi
   settings, it shows as off again.
2. It does have a keyboard shortcut to enable/disable WiFi (Fn + F3), but that does nothing at all. (the other F-key hotkeys work).
   This machine does not have a hardware switch for WiFi.
3. Reinstalled WiFi driver.
4. Replaced WiFi card, installed drivers.
5. Disabled power management (don't allow Windows to turn off wireless)
6. Found a couple posts that said with Intel cards to disable 40hz. Now explicit setting for that here, but found one similar and changing it did nothing.
7. I don't see anything in the BIOS for enabling/disabling it.
8. Restarted machine multiple times. Also pulled battery and cord and held power for 30 seconds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's now working after multiple restarts and continues to work after more. The WiFi hotkey (Fn+F3) does work, but only if held about 5 seconds. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

I installed RF Button driver for Win 8.1 from another model and FN+F3 is working again. The name of the ZIP archive is Others_Dritek_2.02.2001.0803_W81x64_A.zip